# Best way to change order of rows in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, row, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table with rows that need to be sorted in a particular order decided by the user. In other words, need the user to be able to insert a new row at a random point in the table, and also move existing rows to a new random location/row number in the table output on a select query...

Solutions I have thought of so far:

1. I could use an integer with an ORDER BY, however,  then i will need to update every row after the point of "insertion".
2. I could use a timestamp and an index integer, set the index integer of the new row to be equal to that of the row currently occupying the point of insertion, and then in the query first order by index, then by timestamp, but the "updating all" problem still occurs when i want to move an old row to a new index, instead of insert a new one.

Comment: MySQL tables don't have any order. The order of results of a query is governed by the `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't use it, they can be returned in any order.

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than your first design.

Comment: Look. When you retrieve rows from any SQL database without giving an `ORDER BY` clause, the server is allowed to return them in whatever order it pleases. The order is *formally unpredictable.* Most of the time the server uses the same order every time you ask for the same set of records, until it doesn't.  Murphy's Law truly applies here: what can go wrong will go wrong, and it will go wrong at the worst possible moment.

Comment: This question was misunderstood to the wildest propertion... Of course the order of rows do not matter in the actual database. What i mean is that i want to store the data with attributes that have an implicit order, so that for each insert, i can specify its priority/position in the select output. The point is that a user of the website should be able to create an ordered list, and then change the order of any element in the list.  So because the order is not preserved by the database itself, i need to specify this using attributes, so that i can order by those attributes with a select query.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most fundamental points of relational databases in general is that the order of the data (as stored) is utterly irrelevant.

If you want retrieved data in a particular order, `select` the data, and specify the required order in an order-by clause.

If you want to specify that order all the time, you might want to create a view, and specify an ordering in the definition of the view (this can still be overridden if you do a `select` on the view that specifies its own `order by` clause).

If you really retrieve all the data from that table in a particular order all (or nearly all) the time, you may want to create a clustered index on that order. This can/will (typically) help in retrieving data in that order.

Answer (score 2):

What @Jerry said is true, the sequence of data in a table is not important. Associated or *related* data is.

For example, if you are trying to record the times of certain events, you need to include a column for that time:

```
item    time
----    ----
one     01:00
two     02:00
four    04:00
```

If you were noting this on paper or a whiteboard or something, a medium that also encompasses *presentation*, you would erase the last row if you wanted to include item "three" at 03:00. But in a database, you can simply insert *(**insert** is sort of a misnomer)* new data to the end of a table:

```
item    time
----    ----
one     01:00
two     02:00
four    04:00
three   03:00
```

The storage of data need not be sequential. When you *present* the data (for human readability or a stockholder report), you then *order* it according to what suits the presentation best.

What if instead of numbered "items" you had names:

```
person    time
----      ----
Betty      01:00
Annie      02:00
Charlie    03:00
```

Here the rows are "in order" by time, but not alphabetically by name. What if a report required you to order data by name?

```
SELECT name, time
FROM mytable
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

**Output:**

```
Annie      02:00
Betty      01:00
Charlie    03:00
```

If you need random order:

```
SELECT name, time
FROM mytable
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Hopefully this additional info helps, as I think *storage* and *presentation* of data are two concepts that you were perhaps tying together.

(A spreadsheet like Excel, for example, in many cases ties together both storage and presentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure out a more elegant alternative? I'm in the same boat, and I'm honestly confused as to how this is not a more popular topic.

Though I think the bottom line is that *there is no alternative* other than storing the "user order" in its own database field.

### My process to keep lists in sync:

- **Inserting into list**

  1. add item to local list
  2. grab the entire ordered local list
  3. insert/update all items, i.e. `INSERT [...] ON EXISTING UPDATE [...]`. This is okay because the number of local rows is lessThanOrEqual the number of database rows.
- **Re-ordering**

  1. same process and reasoning as above.
- **Removing from list**

  1. delete item locally
  2. delete item from database (*this is key*, as it prevents the list from having excess items with the same order -- alternatively, you could delete all items in the list, and while it's less error-prone, it seems dumb and overkill)
  3. (same as above) grab the entire ordered local list
  4. (same as above) insert/update all items, i.e. `INSERT [...] ON EXISTING UPDATE [...]`. This is okay because, after the deletion, the number of local rows is lessThanOrEqual the number of database rows

The process still feels weird, especially the idea of updating the entire list when just one item is added, deleted, or modified (changes order).

Side note: I stupidly ran into an issue because in a specific situation I was removing the local item, then simply updating the rows in the database. At first, logically it makes sense, but the reality is that we're not updating *all* the rows in the database, just the ones that overlap both locally and on the db, which left the extra one on the db untouched (the one I deleted locally). So my db table had more items than the "order" column implied, and was therefore out of sync with local. To make things worse, I was using locally the "user order" as Dictionary index, so while I was retrieving all of the items from the db, I was then overwriting items with those with the same order (caused by not explicitly deleting the item in the db), making even more of a mess.